# Excel: Sum of each individuals across multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets labeled Summary, April through November 2017.  For each month sheets, I have listings of each employees, titles, billing rates, hours and fee amount (billing rates x hours).

What I would like to do is in the summary sheet, I have created a chart with all employees names with their title, billing rates and fee amounts and would like to calculate each hours and fee amount across all sheets into this one chart.

If you can spell out the steps that I need to do this, that would be great.

Thanks for all your anticipated help.

Raymond

Comment: So you mean `Summary!E42` would be ```April!C42*April!D42+May!C42*May!D42+June!C42*June!D42+...+November!C42*November!D42```? I presume you will want the solution to adapt automatically next month to include `December`. What happens in January? What have you tried?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 3D SUM for stuff like this.

```
=SUM(January:December!A1)
```

The above will sum up all Values in A1 from sheet called January to December.

See below for more info on what can be used within a 3D function

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/09/excel-3d-reference-formula/